# npx is not using yarn even though yarn is installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I installed node js and yarn on mac os. Both yarn and npm work. But when I try to create a creat app using the following command react app is created with npm.

How could I make yarn the default package manager for npx?

`npx create-react-app`

Kindly help me with this.

On my windows PC npx works with yarn. In mac though yarn is installed npx uses npm

Answer (score 0):

npx will always use npm. This cannot be changed.

With yarn you may start a new project by `yarn create react-app my-app` instead.